# Sub won't open MS word (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a macro that builds reports in Word (This macro was not written by me, nor does the person who wrote it still work here). Anyway, it runs fine on my coworkers PC but will not run on mine (I have a surface pro 3 if that matters).

When I run the macro it fails on: `Set VAVdoc = WordApp.Documents.Add`

When it fails I receive the following error:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

I am at a loss as to why it will not run on my setup but it will on my co-workers. Any ideas?

Any help greatly appreciated.
Update: After trying:

> Set o = CreateObject("Word Application")

again without the o.quit I get the error

> ActiveX component can't create object

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim HVACdoc As Word.Document, VAVdoc As Word.Document, CDWdoc As Word.Document
Dim FullName As String, ShortName As String, TrendMonth As String, TrendYear As String, StartTrend As String, EndTrend As String
Dim ChartName As String, Directory As String, FolderName As String
Dim VAVName As String, VAVLocation As String, HVACName As String, HVACLocation As String, CDWName As String, CDWLocation As String

Call WorksheetCall("AHU-1")

FullName = "Mossman Building"
ShortName = "Mossman"
TrendMonth = MonthName(Month(Cells(4, 3)))
TrendYear = Year(Cells(4, 3))
StartTrend = Format(Cells(4, 3), "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")
EndTrend = Format(Cells(4, 3) + 6, "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")

Directory = "P:\M&V\- Projects\UNC-G\UNCG Year 7 Report"
FolderName = MonthName(Month(Cells(4, 3)), True) & " " & TrendYear
VAVName = FolderName & " - " & ShortName & " C.2.3.docx"
VAVLocation = Directory & FolderName & "\" & VAVName
HVACName = FolderName & " - " & ShortName & " C.2.4.docx"
HVACLocation = Directory & FolderName & "\" & HVACName
CDWName = FolderName & " - " & ShortName & " C.2.5.docx"
CDWLocation = Directory & FolderName & "\" & CDWName

On Error Resume Next
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.number <> 0 Then
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Call DefineDescriptions(TrendMonth, TrendYear, StartTrend, EndTrend)

'Report C.2.3 - VAV Conversion

If Dir(VAVLocation) = "" Then
    Set VAVdoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
    VAVdoc.SaveAs (VAVLocation)
End If
```

Comment: You could have a look at the Local window if the error occurs. How the `WordApp` is displayed there? Is it anything or is it `Nothing`? Please look in the VBA Editor (`Tools - References`) which reference `Microsoft Word ??? Object Library` is selected there. Which Office version are you using?

Comment: I am using Office 2010. The value of VAVdoc when it fails is Nothing. The reference that is selected is Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library.

Comment: O sorry. I missed that. In the locals window the WordApp value is Nothing (type is application).

Comment: Hm, so both `GetObject(, "Word.Application")` and `CreateObject("Word.Application")` has failed. But the reference seems to be right. Can you put a Sub in the VBA Editor which only contains the line `Set o = CreateObject("Word.Application"): o.Quit` and step through this with `F8`? Which error occurs?

Comment: So when I add the new sub that only contains the code you mentioned it runs just fine. Very odd.

Edit: After running the code excel seems to hang itself and wont close. I get: "Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action."

Comment: Please look at the Task Manager and close all running Word applications. Now try again.

Comment: It runs just fine. No errors thrown.

Comment: That points to that there are nevertheless versions conflicts with the Microsoft Word Object Library. Hm, the solution would be using late binding instead of early binding. But this leads to radically changes of the code. In your code snippet it would be not as much. Only change the `DIM ... as Word...` to `DIM ... as Object`.  But if the other code uses `wd...` constants then all of them must be replaced with their values.

Comment: Or last try: Are there other references `Microsoft Word ??? Object Library` available? If so, then try deselect the `Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library`, select another Microsoft Word Object Library and try your early binding macro again until it runs. I hope there are not as much possibilities ;-).

Comment: Well I took some of your advice and tinkered around with the code. So now I run into a new error: Library Not Found. Then if you run it again it hangs itself (like earlier). When I force kill it I get the following error: "Automation error The remote procedure call failed". Progress.

Comment: When I declare a word application from excel I always declare it as Object:  `Dim appWord As Object`.  Has you tried this?

Comment: I have tried setting the WordApp as an Object. However, I think my biggest problem is that ActiveX wont even create a new instance of word in a very simple line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a solution but a debugging hint.

At first in Task Manager close all running Word applications.

In `Tools - References` deselect all the references to `Microsoft Word ??? Object Library`.

Now try the following Macro. Step through it with `F8`. But at the end also through the `.Close` and `.Quit`. Because if you don't there were unused Word processes collected in the system.

```
Sub testWordAppLateBinding()

 Dim oWordApp As Object
 Dim oWordDoc As Object

 Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 oWordApp.Visible = True
 Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Add



 oWordDoc.Close
 oWordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Does this work? Is there Word opened with a new document? If so, then late binding works. If not, which errors occurs?

Now in `Tools - References` select the reference to `Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library` and try the following Macro:

```
Sub testWordAppEarlyBinding()

 Dim oWordApp As Word.Application
 Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document

 Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 oWordApp.Visible = True
 Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Add



 oWordDoc.Close
 oWordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Does this work also? Is there Word opened with a new document? If so, then early binding works also. If so, then the error is elsewhere. If not, but late binding works, then you have to change your code to late binding.

If nothing works, sure you can start the Word application manually at all? Is Word starting without dialogs? Or which dialogs were displayed?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Excel is now opening and editing Word.  Early bindings was the problem. I switched over to late bindings (Only a few changes were required) and it now works. Much appreciated.